# Как отправить FormData как параметры GET-запроса?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы поля формы someForm превратились в get-параметры? Есть ли какой-то нормальный способ для этого?

```js
var formData = new FormData(someForm);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/ajax-handler/', true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

То есть чтобы на сервер в итоге приходил запрос по адресу вида /ajax-handler/?param1=1&param2=2

Comment: `new URLSearchParams(someForm).toString()`

Comment: Если GET - то urlencoded, если FormData - то POST, который будет иметь формат multipart/form-data. Если Вам нужно использовать GET, то не используйте FormData. https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms#kodirovka-multipart-form-data